# Иероглифы вместо русского текста в коде

Tags: c++

Переустановил Windows, поставив английскую версию (United States). После этого все файлы кода в Visual Studio, которые были написаны на русской версии, искажены, а именно комментарии на русском. Как я понимаю, проблема в несоответствии кодировок Windows и самого файла. Можно ли исправить эту ситуацию так, чтобы при открытии любого файла комментарии были понятны? (вот скриншот)[image: один из файлов]

Comment: кодировка файла не такая, какую ждёт VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вы сохраняли в однобайтовой кодировке Windows 1251. Возьмите Notepad++ и пересохраните в UTF-8. Ну и в последующем сохраняйте докуметы в UTF-8.

Comment: Я открыл этот файл через блокнот (на английской версии Windows) поменял кодировку на UTF-8, снова открыл и ничего не решилось. Может есть возможность прямо в Visual Studio 2019 изменить кодировку .cpp файла?

Comment: @DemienBlogan Я же уже написал, что необходимо взять Notepad++, открыть в нем файл в кодировке Windows 1251 и сохранить в кодировке UTF8.

Comment: да, через Notepad++ заработало. Но нужно как-то решить эту проблему без посторонних программ, например через Windows или Visual Studio 2019. Я преподаватель и на компьютерах моих студентов нельзя поставить эту программу, но у них такая же беда. Кстати, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @DemienBlogan Ну сохранять в UTF8 в студии можно без проблем. Есть даже расширение [ForceUTF8 (with BOM)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jz5.ForceUTF8withBOM) чтобы сделать сохранение в такой кодировке поведением по-умолчанию. А вот открыть файл в однобайтовой кодировке иначе как с текущей локалью в VS вроде бы нельзя. Для массовой перекодировки можно попробовать написать PS скрипт.